# How do I find out which users that's not been active within a time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This script down below demonstrates how I find out which users that's been active within a time period. How do I figure which users that's not been active within this time interval?

```
USE Database

SELECT 
      a.CreationDate
    , c.UserName AS Name
    , b.Fullname as DepartmentName
    , c.FirstName as Forename
    , c.LastName as Surname
FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] as a
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Departments] as b ON a.DepartmentID =b.DepartmentID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Users] as c ON c.UserID =a.UserID
WHERE (a.CreationDate) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Users] u  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] ct
                  WHERE c.tUserID = u.UserID AND ct.CreationDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' 
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Gordon. I appreciate your help

Comment: @AbdirahmanYasin . . . If your question has been answered, you should accept whichever of the answers you think is best.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your `WHERE` clause to something like:

```
...
WHERE a.CreationDate < '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24580256)

Comment: Why does this 'not provide a answer to the question'? When the User changes the where clause - I think the Statement should workd, so he/she gets the wanted result...

Comment: Yours is correct assuming a user can only be in the case table `a` once. If users have multiple entries in the case table, your `where` clause may return users who were active before the window, but also within it. Since the question didn't specify, this answer works better as a comment to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Would `NOT BETWEEN` be the right solution for you?
¨

```
SELECT a.CreationDate
      ,c.UserName AS Name
      ,b.Fullname as DepartmentName
      ,c.FirstName as Forename
      ,c.LastName as Surname
FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] as a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Departments] as b ON a.DepartmentID =b.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Users] as c ON c.UserID =a.UserID
WHERE (a.CreationDate) not between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
```

For example here is a small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7cd7a2b6d601d6c461e5d1d56399ee83)